# Extracting repeating substrings using regex

Tags: r, regex, regexp-replace

I am trying to remove substrings that start after **":"** using regex in r.

```
"Disaster - Natural (ex - fire, tornado, flood, etc.): Flood 1/1/2020;Event - Income: 1/1/2020;Disaster - Natural (ex - fire, tornado, flood, etc.): Fire"

"Disaster - Natural (ex - fire, tornado, flood, etc.): Flood 1/1/2020"

"Event - Health; Disaster - Natural (ex - fire, tornado, flood, etc.): Fire"
```

In this example I am trying to remove "Flood 1/1/2020", "1/1/2020", and "Fire" after each delimited category. The words and dates after each ":" vary. The data is structured within a column with each row varying in amount of delimited categories.

Regex is a weak point for me. Many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a regex like below

```
gsub(":.*?(;|$)","\\1",s,perl = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
[1] "Disaster - Natural (ex - fire, tornado, flood, etc.);Event - Income;Disaster - Natural (ex - fire, tornado, flood, etc.)"
- fire, tornado, flood, etc.)"
[2] "Disaster - Natural (ex - fire, tornado, flood, etc.)"
[3] "Event - Health; Disaster - Natural (ex - fire, tornado, flood, etc.)"
```

**Data**

```
s <- c("Disaster - Natural (ex - fire, tornado, flood, etc.): Flood 1/1/2020;Event - Income: 1/1/2020;Disaster - Natural (ex - fire, tornado, flood, etc.): Fire",
"Disaster - Natural (ex - fire, tornado, flood, etc.): Flood 1/1/2020",
"Event - Health; Disaster - Natural (ex - fire, tornado, flood, etc.): Fire"
)
```

Comment: That is very close to what I am trying to achieve. The only thing I would want to keep is the ";" delimiter between each category in the rows. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

An option with `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(s, "Flood \\d+/\\d+/\\d{4}|:\\s+Fire")
```

-output

```
#[1] "Disaster - Natural (ex - fire, tornado, flood, etc.): ;Event - Income: 1/1/2020;Disaster - Natural (ex - fire, tornado, flood, etc.)"
#[2] "Disaster - Natural (ex - fire, tornado, flood, etc.): "                                                                              
#[3] "Event - Health; Disaster - Natural (ex - fire, tornado, flood, etc.)"
```

#### data

```
s <- c("Disaster - Natural (ex - fire, tornado, flood, etc.): Flood 1/1/2020;Event - Income: 1/1/2020;Disaster - Natural (ex - fire, tornado, flood, etc.): Fire", 
"Disaster - Natural (ex - fire, tornado, flood, etc.): Flood 1/1/2020", 
"Event - Health; Disaster - Natural (ex - fire, tornado, flood, etc.): Fire"
)
```